Nesting Formulas In A Flow
I'm building a flow that has two formula resources. One of these formulas is used heavily as part of the other formula. I wasn't able to find a clear answer on whether formula resources in flows are also calculated on demand as formula fields on an object, or whether they were calculated at the start of a flow interview and the output stored behind the scenes.
I'm trying to ensure the flow is built efficiently and if formulas are calculated on demand then nesting one formula into another doesn't seem like the best approach. If that is the case, then I was considering calculating the first formula at the beginning of the flow and storing the value in a constant variable and then referencing that constant variable in the other formula. Is this a good approach or is there no need?

Formulas are evaluated when they are used.
To test this, I set up two number variables:

Number1
Number2

Then I created a formula:

Name: Number1Value
Type: Number
Formula: {!Number1}

I then used these values in an Assignment element:

{!Number1} equals 5
{!Number2} equals {!Number1Value}
{!Number1} equals 10
{!Number2} equals {!Number1Value}

When debugging, I got this output:


{!Number1} Equals 5
{!Number2} Equals {!Number1Value}
{!Number1} Equals 10
{!Number2} Equals {!Number1Value}

Result

{!ANumber} = "10.00"
{!ANumber2} = "10.00"


Which definitively proves that they are evaluated on demand.
To prevent repeated executions to save on resources, you can create a variable, assign the formula to that variable, then use the variable for the rest of the flow.


So then nesting formulas are quite inefficient. Is there a better approach to this?

@eHarazi your other idea, calculating once and storing in a variable, will work just fine. It's a trick I've also used in the past.

It would be great to know how this would get setup and how it would be different. I can see with a variable, I can select the formula as the "Default Value". However, when would this variable be executed? If it's executed on demand, isn't it more of the same?

@eHarazi Create a variable and your formula, and at the beginning, use the Assignment element to assign the formula's value to the variable. You can then reference the variable in the rest of your flow, including the second formula, so that the first formula doesn't need to calculate the value time and time again. I'll add a graphic or two.
